# How to give one function id to other function in controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I want to give company id to other function which I am getting in the `companyProfileDetails()`

My code in controller is:

```
public function company_profile()
{
    $data['compData'] = $this->company_model->companyProfileDetails($this->session->userdata('peo_id'));
    $data['compAgentData'] = $this->company_model->companyAgentDetails($compData->cmp_id);
    $this->load->view('company_profile',$data);
}
```

My code in model:

```
public function companyProfileDetails($peo_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM company left join people_company on people_company.pcy_company_id = company.cmp_id where people_company.pcy_people_id ='".$peo_id."'";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->row();
}

public function companyAgentDetails($cmp_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT peo_id,peo_name FROM people_company left join people on people.peo_id = people_company.pcy_people_id WHERE people_company.pcy_company_id ='23' ";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..

```
public function company_profile()
{ 

    $data['compData'] = $this->company_model->companyProfileDetails($this->session->userdata('peo_id'));

    $data['compAgentData'] = $this->company_model->companyAgentDetails($data['compData']->cmp_id);
    $this->load->view('company_profile',$data);
}
```

OR

```
public function company_profile()
{ 
    $compData = $this->company_model->companyProfileDetails($this->session->userdata('peo_id'));//Get row data

     $id = $compData->cmp_id;//get row's id
    $data['compAgentData'] = $this->company_model->companyAgentDetails($id);
    $data['compData'] = $compData;
    $this->load->view('company_profile',$data);
}
```

Comment: @Vidhya welcome best of luck ahead.and vote up answer. thanks